# Mono<ClientResponse> is always returning a null object from a WebClient post request

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have the following code in a unit test in an effort to understand the WebClient API:-

```
@BeforeEach
    public void setUpTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
        baseUrl = String.format("http://localhost:%s", mockBackEnd.getPort());
        String response = "Some string response";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mockBackEnd.enqueue(new MockResponse()
                .setBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(response))
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_clientResponse_return_type() {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build();

        Mono<ClientResponse> clientResponseMono = webClient.post()
                .uri(baseUrl)
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .bodyValue("")
                .exchangeToMono(Mono::just);

        ClientResponse clientResponse = clientResponseMono.block();

        log.info("Response StatusCode is :-" + clientResponse.statusCode());

        log.info("Response Body is :-" + clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class).block());

    }
```

Unfortunately the StatusCode message prints out correctly and gives me a 200 OK, however, the responseBody is invariably null?

This is not the case however when I use the deprecated '.exchange()' method along with a block instead of using the Mono and I get the expected response 'Some String Response'

```
ClientResponse clientResponse = webClient.post()
                .uri(baseUrl)
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .bodyValue("")
                .exchange()
                .block();
```

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official documentation [explicitly states](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient/client-exchange.html):

> When using [exchange], after the returned Mono or Flux completes, the response body is checked and if not consumed it is released to prevent memory and connection leaks.

It means that when you do `clientResponseMono.block()`, the response body is discarded, and you cannot use it anymore.

You have to consume the body in the functino that create the returned mono:

```java
        Mono<String> bodyMono = webClient.post()
                .uri(baseUrl)
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .bodyValue("")
                .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                    log.info("Response StatusCode is :-" + response.statusCode());
                    return response.bodyToMono(String.class);
                });
        log.info("Response Body is :-" + bodyMono.block());
```

**UPDATE**:

If you want a result containing both status code and body, you can adapt the exchange function as follow:

```java
record Response<B>(HttpStatus status, B body) {}
Mono<Response<String>> = webClient.post()
                .uri(baseUrl)
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .bodyValue("")
                .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                    var status = response.getStatusCode();
                    return response.bodyToMono(String.class)
                                   .map(body -> new Response(status, body);
                });
```

Comment: Thanks Amanin for your response and your code snippet. the thing is I'm using a dev.failsafe.Failsafe.with around my WebClient and for that I need access to return an object that has access to both the statusCode and the responseBody. Unfortunately the only way I could appear to achieve this was with the .exchange() method but that's unfortunately deprecated so or ArchUnit tests break. Is this possible with the .exchangeToMono() method?

Comment: @MarkGargan Can't you use `Mono.retryWhen` instead ? Because mixing reactive and imperative operators will be difficult.

Comment: @MarkGargan: I've added an example showing how to get back both status and body from response. I think that should meet your requirements. Note, however, that if you plan to use `block` with webflux webclient, you lose most (all ?) benefits of the reactive stack. In this case, maybe using another imperative http client would be better (Java 11 HttpClient, or Spring new HttpClient, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Amanin, that's what I went with in the end. Thanks for your help on this. I'll mark your answer as answered as it did answer the initial question